# 'User' object has no attribute 'is_verified'

Tags: python, django, attributeerror, two-factor-authentication, django-two-factor-auth

I'm having this error. All of a sudden it was working fine on my local. but when I tried to deploy the app I have this error, I'm using a package `two_factor` Otp, here is the traceback
Traceback:

```
File "/tmp/8d909c171bfae2c/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/tmp/8d909c171bfae2c/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/tmp/8d909c171bfae2c/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/tmp/8d909c171bfae2c/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in wrapper
  241.                 return self.admin_view(view, cacheable)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/tmp/8d909c171bfae2c/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/tmp/8d909c171bfae2c/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/tmp/8d909c171bfae2c/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  212.             if not self.has_permission(request):

File "/tmp/8d909c171bfae2c/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/two_factor/admin.py" in has_permission
  28.         return request.user.is_verified()

File "/tmp/8d909c171bfae2c/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in inner
  257.         return func(self._wrapped, *args)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /
Exception Value: 'User' object has no attribute 'is_verified'
```

any help would be appreciated. thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is because you didn't add the middleware in.  In your settings.py, find the MIDDLEWARE variable.  Under

```
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
```

add

```
'django_otp.middleware.OTPMiddleware',
```

Also make sure do apply the migrations:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: Keep in mind it must be UNDER the auth middleware otherwise it will not work.

Answer (score 1):

You should add `OTPMiddleware` just after [AuthenticationMiddleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/middleware/#django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware) according to [the doc](https://django-two-factor-auth.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html#setup) as shown below:

```py
# "settings.py"

MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django_otp.middleware.OTPMiddleware' # Here
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You must call authenticate before you can call login.

authenticate sets an attribute on the object, which means backend has successfully validated it and clearing it for login.

Or

you can use is_authenticated

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/auth/

Comment: How im suposed to do that? i mean which files i should change ? And thanks for your answer.

Comment: you can use is_authenticated

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/auth/